# Convert UL into JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to convert an entire UL and it's children elements into a JSON object.

This is what we did:

```
function getData(el) {
    el.find('li').each(function () {
        data.push({ "nome": $(this).find('span').html(), "cargo": $(this).find('strong').html()  });
    });
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cbzo0ef2/2/

But all elements are in the same level. In this case, all levels need to be kept.

Comment: Can you specify the json format in which you want the output?Not getting what you mean by "all levels need to be kept"

Comment: If you want an object, why are you using an array?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parents("ul").length` would be trick for you:

```
function getData(el) {
    el.find('li').each(function () {
        data.push({ "nome": $(this).find('span').html(), "cargo": $(this).find('strong').html(), "dept": $(this).parents("ul").length  })
    });
  }
```

You need extra work to render dept to your json structure

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yeh600p/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will retain the levels in your HTML:

```
(function($) {

    function getData(el) {
        var data = [];

        el.children('li').each(function () {
            var currentElement = $(this);

            var nomeElement = currentElement.children('span')[0];
            var cargoElement = currentElement.children('strong')[0];

            var item = {};

            if (nomeElement && cargoElement) {
                item.nome = $(nomeElement).html();
                item.cargo = $(cargoElement).html();
            }

            data.push(item);

            var child = currentElement.children('ul')[0];

            if (child != null) {
                item.children = getData($(child));
            }
        });

        return data;
    }

    var data = getData($('.root'));
    console.log(data);

})(jQuery);
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/52t58551/

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery Children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and some recursion you can get every node.

```js
(function($) {
  function getData(el) {
    var curr = [];
    el.children('li, ul').each(function(i, child) {
      curr.push({
        nodeName: child.nodeName,
        nome: $(child).find("> span").text(),
        cargo: $(child).find("> strong").text(),
        subLevel: getData($(child))
      });
    });
    return curr
  }

  var result = getData($('.root'));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="root"> <li><span>a</span><strong>b</strong></li><li><span>c</span><strong>d</strong></li><li><span>e</span><strong>f</strong></li><li> <ul> <li><span>g</span><strong>h</strong></li><li><span>i</span><strong>j</strong></li><li> <ul> <li><span>k</span><strong>l</strong></li></ul> </li></ul> </li></ul>
```